# Observable Pattern Implementation not calling update method

Tags: java, observer-pattern, observable

I am working to implement the Observable Design pattern on code that was provided for an assignment.  I don't want the whole answer, but I do want to understand what is missing.  I won't copy all of the code, but the pertinent pieces that I a have written so far.  The code is a simple banking GUI that allows us to save Savings and Checking accounts to an ArrayList.  My first step was to pull that out into a new object AccountList and extend Observable as such:

```
public class AccountList extends Observable {
public List<AAccount> accountList;

public AccountList(List<AAccount> accountList) {
    this.accountList = accountList;
}

public void add(AAccount acc) {
    accountList.add(acc);
    hasChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
}
```

My next step was to implement an observer class as such:

```
public class AccountListObserver implements Observer{

public AccountListObserver(Observable o) {
    o.addObserver(this);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    System.out.println("Account " + o + " has been added, " +
            "there are now " + o + " accounts on the server.");

}
}
```

Now within the actual Server class I have the following called out in the beginning:

```
AccountList accList = new AccountList(new ArrayList<AAccount>());
Observer accObserver = new AccountListObserver(accList);
```

Then whenever an account is added I am calling accList.add(acc)

I am not getting my output but the program runs fine.  What piece(s) am I missing to make this functional.  Once I understand what is missing or needs to be moved/changed, I can make the necessary changes for all of the functions.  I am just very confused by what could be missing because it seems like a logical configuration.

Comment: Replace call to `hasChanged()` with `setChanged()` and try.

Comment: Wow...I knew it was something that simple.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You can typecast `o` to `AccountList ` in the `update` method. And from there you can get `Account` objects. `AccountList accList = (AccountList) o;`

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused because casting it to AccountList lets me call the AccountList functions, but if I wanted, as an example, the getName function from Account, how would I reference it through that dependency tree?  Basically I want the update call to be able to reference the getName for the account it just added to AccountList.

Comment: if you want to get access to the account that just got added, try the overloaded `notifyObservers(Object )` method instead of `notifyObservers()`. You can use `notifyObservers(acc)` and this `acc` can be accessed through the second parameter  i.e., `arg` of  `update(Observable o, Object arg)` method.

Comment: I just figured that out ironically, but that is exactly what I did.  I was browsing the API for Observable and noticed the overloaded method.  That was exactly what I needed, but thank you for the help.  Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace call to `hasChanged()` with `setChanged()`. This sets the changed flag to true and allows `notifyObservers()` method to notify the observers.

Comment: Thank you so much!  So I guess my last piece of confusion is how to reference the Account and AccountList attributes (name, balance, etc) in the update method since it is actually referencing the Observable object 'o'. Is there an easy way to do this?